# How do I unlock a file on a Windows Server 2012 file cluster

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

We have a "Continuous Availability"-enabled fileshare on a Windows Server 2012 cluster. A config file used by our web application, `application.config` has been corrupted somehow and is now zero-bytes, but more importantly seems to be locked.

Any edits to the file fail, with errors about the file being open or locked.

I have checked the "open files" dialog in Windows, and whilst there are many handles to the file open, none seem to have a lock.

ProcessExplorer shows handles for the file, but they're all owned by `SYSTEM` because it's all remote share activity.

I have tried failing the cluster over, but of course the "Continuous availability" cheerfully and invisibly migrates the file locks to the new node.

Is there a way of forcibly and without question terminating all locks on a file?

Things tried:

- Just stopping the entire W3SVC on the webs, in case that unlocked the file
- Using FileAssassin to unlock the file, unload all modules using the file, and then kill the process locking the file
- Rebooted Node.
- Set the Windows registry key that deletes files on bootup and rebooted the node.

I have paused the second node so that any reboots of the first didn't just move the disk to it.

Comment: Shut down the web app that's using the file?

Comment: We stopped the AppPools on all the web servers in the group, but that didn't seem to help.